# How to make UIViewControllers support different orientations

Tags: objective-c, rotation, uiinterfaceorientation

I have two UIViewControllers, and one should only support portrait orientation, and the other should support both portait and landscape orientations. I have tried overriding the`- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations` method to return `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait`, as well as overriding the `shouldAutorotate` method to return NO for the UIViewController that should only support portrait orientation, but nothing is working. Can someone help me out here?

Comment: "Nothing is working" means what, exactly? Is the portrait+landscape VC not rotating? In which orientation is it stuck? Is the portrait-only VC rotating to landscape? Both? And finally, what orientations do you support in the `Info.plist` file? From the UIViewController docs for `supportedInterfaceOrientations`: "The system intersects the view controller’s supported orientations with the app's supported orientations [...] to determine whether to rotate."

Comment: What I mean by that is the UIViewController is rotating to landscape when the device is rotated, when I want it to only support portait orientation. I am supporting landscape and portrait orientations in the `Info.plist` file.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Next question: Can you confirm that your `supportedInterfaceOrientations` implementation is invoked at all? Again from the docs for `supportedInterfaceOrientations`: "[...] the system calls this method on the root view controller or the topmost presented view controller that fills the window." So if your VC is embedded, i.e. not presented, its `supportedInterfaceOrientations` implementation might be totally ignored.

Comment: It is being called, and now that I am running the app in the simulator, the method is working, and the VC isn't supporting landscape orientation. But it on my device, the VC is supporting landscape orientation.

Comment: Hm, wait, I just noticed another sentence in the docs: "This method is only called if the view controller’s `shouldAutorotate` method returns `YES`." So in my understanding `supportedInterfaceOrientations` shouldn't be invoked after all, since you say that you return `NO` in your `shouldAutorotate` implementation. Quite mysterious.